# How to check if a line segment is the extension of another?

Tags: python, extend, lines, intersect

What if I have 2 line segments that is defined by two starting and ending points such as below:

line segment 1 starts [0,0] and ends at [5,0] 
another line segment 2 starts at [3,0] and ends at [8,0]

How do I check that line segment 2 extends out of line segment 2 and also if the two line segments aren't necessarily horizontal nor vertical but at a slope?
Is there a generalized code for that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a python question, rather it is all simple math.

Comment: If they overlap, one end point of line A must lie on line B and vice versa.

Comment: @tobias_k: Not vice versa. One of the line segments might be completely contained in the other.

Comment: @cfh But then it is not "the extension" of the other. (At least by my intuitive understanding of "extending" something the extension should not be entirely contained within the thing it extends)

Comment: @tobias_k: By what definition?

Comment: I've already handled when one segment is inside another but haven't known how to see the case that I asked above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy` linear regressions to save yourself some pretty obvious but lengthy code:

```
x1 = np.array([0, 5])
y1 = np.array([0, 0])

x2 = np.array([3, 0])
y2 = np.array([8, 0])

data1 = scipy.stats.linregress(x1, y1)
data2 = scipy.stats.linregress(x2, y2)

m1, b1 = data1[:2] # slope and intercept of 1st line
m2, b2 = data2[:2] # slope and intercept of 2nd line

if m1 == m2 and b1 == b2:
    print 'These are extensions'
```